# this channel already in use, continouing anyway

Tags: gpio

[image]

why does every program always appear like this? What's wrong with me?

Comment: Or as suggested, use "GPIO.setwarnings(False)" at the beginning of your python program (after import, before setting up input/output mode) to disable warnings.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. It's unreadable for old eyes. Instead paste the text direct into the question.

Answer (score 3):

Your previous program run must have exited but left GPIO pins in use. The next run of the program is warning you that it is reassigning pins that are in use. If you execute

```
GPIO.cleanup()
```

before the program exits then it won't happen.